# How to set a php variable from PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global-variables

I have a custom term meta field in wordpress, and I currently use this code to display it:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'camera');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$term_id = $term->term_id;
echo get_term_meta( $term_id, 'model', true );
}?>
```

However, I need to display this meta data multiple times in a few pages. I tried creating a global variable, but I am having no luck.

This is what I tried:

I put this in my functions.php:

```
$camera = <"?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'camera');
         foreach ($terms as $term) {
         $term_id = $term->term_id;
         echo get_term_meta( $term_id, 'model', true );
         }?">
```

And then I put this in my template file:

```
<p><?php global $camera;echo $camera;?><p/>
```

But it is not working.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you requiring the file?

Comment: @Script47 I am requiring the field data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `camera` in `functions.php`. So why do you not make it one?

functions.php

```
<?php 
function camera() {
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'camera');
    $result = "";
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $result .= get_term_meta( $term_id, 'model', true );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then `require("functions.php");` in `template.php`, and you will be able to simply call `camera()`:

template.php

```
<?php
require("functions.php");

... other code and html ...

<p><?php echo camera(); ?></p>
```

Comment: I would like it to be a variable ($camera), not an array please.

Comment: I assumed you wanted a function because you defined `$camera` in `functions.php`, but to make it a variable you want to remove the function declaration and `return` and rename `$result` to `$camera`.

Comment: Thanks @Uncreative Name for your reply! I tried that, but I am getting the following error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: When I do `var_dump($camera)` I get `string(0) ""` even though there is data in the taxonomy term meta. Any ideas?